# Issues querying on a partitioned CosmosDB collection

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

I Am trying to do a cross partition query on Azure CosmosDB without a partition key. The throughput is set to be 4000, I get 250RU/s per partition key range.

My cosmos db collection has about 1million documents and is a total of 70gb in size. They are spread evenly across approx 40,000 logical partitions, the json documents are on average 100kb in size. This is what the structure of my json documents look like:

```
"ArrayOfObjects": [
 {
     // other properties omitted for brevity
     "SubId": "ed2a49fb-51d4-45b4-9690-df0721d6a32f"
 },
 {
     "SubId": "35c87833-9bea-4151-86da-4d9c482ae1fe"
 },
 "ParitionKey": "b42"
```

This is how I am querying currently without a partition key:

```
public async Task<ResponseModel> GetBySubId(string subId)
{
    var collectionId = _cosmosClient.CollectionId;
    var query = $@"SELECT * FROM {collectionId} c
                   WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.ArrayOfObjects, {{'SubId': '{subId}'}}, true)";

    var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };

    var docQuery = _cosmosClient.Client.CreateDocumentQuery(
            _collectionUri,
            query,
            feedOptions)
            .AsDocumentQuery();

    var results = new List<ResponseModel>();
    while (docQuery.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var executedQuery = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<ResponseModel>();
        if (executedQuery.Count != 0)
        {
            results.AddRange(executedQuery.ToList());
        }
    }

    if (results.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return results.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I am expecting to to be able to retrieve the document via one of the `SubId`'s right after inserting it. What actually happens is that it is unable to get the document and returns back null even after the query finishes execution by draining all continuation tokens. This issue is intermittent and inconsistent as sometimes it can get the document after it is inserted other times not.

For those documents that are failing to be retrieved after being inserted, if you wait some time (a couple  of minutes usually) and repeat the query with the same `SubId` it is able to then retrieve the document. There seems to be a delay.

I have checked the cosmosdb metrics in the Azure portal, the metrics indicate that I have not exceeded the provisioned RU/s per partition at all or that there has been any rate limiting in my requests (HTTP 429).

Given the above why am I still seeing issues with cross partition querying even when there is enough throughput provisioned?

Comment: It seems that your problem can be summarized as _sometimes I don't read my own writes_ so this could be an issue with your [consistency level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels). What is the default consistency level of the container and do you override that when inserting the data?

Comment: I have tried with both strong and eventual consistency, it didn't make any difference.